# Filling a dropdownlist in a grid view with manual data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to fill a dropdownlist within a gridview with manual data.  Is there anyway to do this through the markup code?  I am just trying to fill it with days etc. 1 day(s), 2 day(s), 3 day(s) etc.  Here is the code for my drop down

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No. Days">
     <ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtFinishDate" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I've tried filling it manually on the page load but it doesn't seem to work and I think it is because of the grid view.  Sorry if the question seems vague and thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a dropdownlist, did you try adding items to the list?

Comment: Yeah in the page load but it didn't work.  I am asking if there is a way to do it through the markup code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have, but you have to add items to the list.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="custom">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="[ select an item ]" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="yes?" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="no?" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="umm..." Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for you've made my life a hell of a lot easier